# How to sync props to state using React hooks : setState()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to set the state using React hook setState() using the props the component receive. I've tried using the below code:

```
import React,{useState , useEffect} from 'react';

const Persons = (props) =>  {

    // console.log(props.name);

   const [nameState , setNameState] = useState(props)

   console.log(nameState.name);
   console.log(props.name);
 
   return (
            <div>
                <p>My name is {props.name} and my age is {props.age}</p>
                <p>My profession is {props.profession}</p>
            </div>
        )

}

export default Persons;
```

The issue is the state is being set upon component being loaded. But when it receive new props, the state is not getting updated. How to update the state in this case?

Comment: Can you add the code in `setNameState`.

Comment: Hi Manav, so can't we sync props to state using useState upon each time the props get updated..?

Comment: no, that line is only initializing your state. if you want to update your state every time with props, you will have to use something like `useEffect`

Answer (score 166, accepted):

`useState` hooks function argument is being used only once and not everytime the prop changes. You must make use of `useEffect` hooks to implement what you would call the `componentWillReceiveProps/getDerivedStateFromProps` functionality

```
import React,{useState , useEffect} from 'react';

const Persons = (props) =>  {
   const [nameState , setNameState] = useState(props)

   useEffect(() => {
       setNameState(props);
   }, [props])

   return (
            <div>
                <p>My name is {props.name} and my age is {props.age}</p>
                <p>My profession is {props.profession}</p>
            </div>
        )

}

export default Persons;
```

Comment: There have been discussions that initializing state from props in an anti-pattern, but since we have hooks, I guess things are changed.  But I am not sure.
What do you think?

Comment: @ImdadulHuqNaim No the things still remain the same, only way of implementing them have changed. It depends whether you need to derive state from props or not. For instance there might be a case where the inputs initial value is provided by props but it still to change locally and update in parent on say submit.

Comment: But doing this re-renders the component again right. This was not the case in getDerivedStateFromProps when we are syncing the props to state.

Comment: Why do you use `props.name` and `props.age` etc. in the return, instead of `nameState.name` & `nameState.age` etc. ?

Comment: This approach looks great, but doesn't this render component twice? Because we are using setState() in useEffect. Doesn't this hit performance?

Comment: Wrong answer, this will result in a wasteful, ghost re-rendering. useEffect has no business being used here.
The simplest way to do it is: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-getderivedstatefromprops

There are more advanced techniques applicable in some cases, like coding a useComputedState hook. Some other suggestions: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

This is a nasty by product of react hooks.

Comment: @AlexG What you suggested also sets a state and causes a re-render.
The docs state: 
`React will re-run the component with updated state immediately after exiting the first render so it wouldn’t be expensive.`

Comment: @supra28  Yes, but It won't actually touch the DOM, as it does in this answer.

Comment: Pls check my answer without additional re-renders.

Comment: This will tigger the useEffect everytime parent component of `Persons` renders

Answer (score 40):

The `props` value in `useState(props)` is used only [during the initial render](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state), further state updates are done with the setter `setNameState`.

In addition, there is no need for `useEffect` when updating [derived state](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html):

```
const Person = props => {
  const [nameState, setNameState] = useState(props.name);
  // update derived state conditionally without useEffect
  if (props.name !== nameState) setNameState(props.name);
  // ... other render code
};
```

From [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-getderivedstatefromprops):

> [...] you can **update the state** right **during rendering**. React will **re-run** the component with updated state immediately **after exiting the first render** so it wouldn’t be expensive.
>
> [...] an update during rendering is exactly what [`getDerivedStateFromProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) has always been like conceptually.

In essence, we can optimize performance by getting rid of an additional browser repaint phase, as `useEffect` always runs after the render is committed to the screen.

#### Working example

This is a contrived example illustrating above pattern - in real code you would read `props.name` directly. See the [React blog post](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html) for more appropriate derived state use cases.

```js
const Person = props => {
  const [nameState, setNameState] = React.useState(props.name);
  // Here, we update derived state without useEffect
  if (props.name !== nameState) setNameState(props.name);

  return (
    <p>
      <h3>Person</h3>
      <div>{nameState} (from derived state)</div>
      <div>{props.name} (from props)</div>
      <p>Note: Derived state is synchronized/contains same value as props.name</p>
    </p>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState("Lui");
  const changeName = () => setPersonName(personName === "Lukas" ? "Lui" : "Lukas");

  return (
    <div>
      <Person name={personName} />
      <button onClick={changeName}>Change props</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-32Gmw5rBDXyMjg/73FgpukoTZdMrxuYW7tj8adbN8z4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-bjQ42ac3EN0GqK40pC9gGi/YixvKyZ24qMP/9HiGW7w=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: But does this hold good if we are getting a whole new object as a prop and we need to sync it to the state. How can we do the deep serach inside an object to check what's changed and what's not?

Comment: Not sure, what you are trying to do. Though you would have to write the deep comparison logic manually, like in above code: `if (props.name.first !== nameState.first)`. Or use a deep comparison helper

Comment: I wish I have seen this answer in the morning... I have just spend a whole day on this problem.

Answer (score 17):

This general idea can be put into hook:

```
export function useStateFromProp(initialValue) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);

  useEffect(() => setValue(initialValue), [initialValue]);

  return [value, setValue];
}


function MyComponent({ value: initialValue }) {
  const [value, setValue] = useStateFromProp(initialValue);

  return (...);
}
```

Comment: For typescript, it's going to want this slightly awkwardly typed version:
export function useStateFromProp<T>(initialValue: T): [T, Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>] {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
  useEffect(() => setValue(initialValue), [initialValue]);
  return [value, setValue];
}

Comment: about the good comment from @chrismarx just add:    import { Dispatch, SetStateAction, useEffect, useState } from "react";

Answer (score 5):

For that, you need to use the `useEffect` so your code looks like.
As you want to avoid to re-render again if pros didn't change then you have to check first on useEffect and then set the props to current variable.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Persons = props => {
  // console.log(props.name);

  const [nameState, setNameState] = useState(props);

  console.log(nameState.name);
  console.log(props.name);
  useEffect(
    () => {
      if (nameState !== props.name) {
        setNameState(props.name);
      }
    },
    [nameState]
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        My name is {props.name} and my age is {props.age}
      </p>
      <p>My profession is {props.profession}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Persons;
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/x3xzxrvxv4)

Comment: This approach looks great, but doesn't this render component twice? Because we are using setState() in useEffect. Doesn't this hit performance?

Comment: @METALHEAD: it will not be called twice because we have also checked if nameState changed then only useEffect should execute, see the second argument of useEffect

Comment: @DhavalPatel The prop changed triggered a render and the `setNameState()` triggers another one. Seems like twice to me.

Answer (score 2):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Persons = props => {
  // console.log(props.name);

  const [nameState, setNameState] = useState(props);

  console.log(nameState.name);
  console.log(props.name);
  useEffect(
    () => {
      if (nameState !== props) {
        setNameState(props);
      }
    },
    [nameState]
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        My name is {props.name} and my age is {props.age}
      </p>
      <p>My profession is {props.profession}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Persons;
```

As per the Hooks react document, all the time when any props is update or any update in component is there then useEffect will be called. So you need to check the condition before updating useState and then update your value so that it continuously doesn't do re-rendering

Answer (score 1):

If you need to calculate state from props and other state **without** additional **re-renders**, consider:

a) Using `useMemo` hook.

```
const Component = ({ name }) => {
  const [surname, setSurname] = useState('');

  const fullName = useMemo(() => {
     return name + ' ' + surname;
  }, [name, surname])

  ...
}
```

b) Calcuating inside render if it is not very heavy:

```
const Component = ({ name }) => {
  const [surname, setSurname] = useState('');

  const fullName = name + ' ' + surname;

  ...
}
```

c) For hard cases where you need to **compare prev props** and should be able to **update state from another place** you can use refs, though it doesn't look good:

```
const Component = ({ name }) => {
  const prevNameRef = useRef()
  const derivedState = useRef();

  if (prevNameRef.current !== name) {
    derivedState.current = ...
    prevNameRef.current = name;
  }
 
  // some other place
  derivedState.current = ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem indicates an attempt to use one *conceptual* variable or set of variables to do two different things.  For example trying to get `props.name` and `name` to do the same thing.

So if

```
const [name, setName] = useState(props.name)
```

isn't enough and you find yourself trying to force `props.name` into state variable `name` later in the function then maybe `name` is being overloaded.   Try setting up another state variable - eg. `updatedName` and see if things work better.

The original example doesn't demonstrate this problem since the state variables are never used except in log statements.

If `const [name, setName] = useState(props.name)` updated on ever re-render there would be no point in having state variable `name` since it would always be the same as `props.name` (and further attempts to change it would cause re-render).

Comment: I believe that my answer is useful - particularly in that it points out that there is no use case in the question since the state variables are only used in logging.   I would love to know why this was voted down.

Answer (score 0):

I figured an alternative solution avoiding `useEffect`. Instead it uses two `useState`'s. I put it into a custom hook for you:

```
export function useStateFromProp(propValue) {
  const [value,          setValue         ] = useState(propValue);
  const [propValueState, setPropValueState] = useState(propValue);

  if (propValueState != propValue) {
    setPropValueState(propValue);
    setValue(propValue);
  }

  return [value, setValue];
}


function MyComponent({ value: propValue }) {
  const [value, setValue] = useStateFromProp(propValue);

  return (...);
}
```

The main benefit would be that now the re-render that was normally triggered by the `useEffect` happens before any child components are re-rendered. so this would be faster.

Disclaimer: I did not test this yet. I did some googling and found this supporting article: https://pretagteam.com/question/in-react-hooks-when-calling-setstate-directly-during-render-is-the-rerender-guaranteed-to-run-before-the-render-of-children