# React hooks useState with props destructuring fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React hooks and trying to set the initial state of a constant inside a component with the passed down `props`. I've seen multiple [examples of this online](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54626764/3909890), but when I do it, the array destructuring returns the whole `props` object, not the instance I want.

```
Import React, {useState} from "react";

const MyComponent = (props) => {
   console.log(props) // {date: "2019-11-26", task: "cooking"}
   const [date, setDate] = useState(props);
   console.log(date) // {date: "2019-11-26, task: "cooking"}

   return (...)
}

export default MyComponent;
```

I'd assume that with object/array destructuring the value of `date` would automatically be assigned the value from `props` (the string `"2019-11-26"`), not the whole `props` object. What am I missing? I can get around this by setting `const [date, setDate] = useState(props.date)` but that breaks eslints react plugins [destructuring rule](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/destructuring-assignment.md) and I'd like to avoid it.

**Edit**

Thanks to [helloitsjoe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8852158/helloitsjoe) for an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59051470/3909890) that solves my problem!

Comment: What does actually fail here?

Comment: *"What am I missing?"* The value of the state is whatever you pass to `useState` and/or `setDate`. `useState` returns an array with two values: The current value of the state and a function to update the state. That has nothing to do with the structure of the value you store in the state.

Comment: *"but that breaks eslints react plugins destructuring rule and I'd like to avoid it."* Did you look at the solutions provided in the documentation for that rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can destructure props in the argument definition. Note that it's best practice if you're setting state from props to name the prop `initialX` or `defaultX` to indicate that it's being set in state, and the state should be used from that point on.

```
const MyComponent = ({ initialDate }) => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(initialDate);

  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works and the comment on the naming best practices was valuable.

Comment: For avoid change the initial value and respect immutability in case of objects, a copy should be done, and fastest way is use the spread operator ( const [date, setDate] = useState(...initialDate);

Comment: It's not necessary to make a copy of an object when setting it as initial state, `setDate` will handle updates immutably. In your example, assuming you mean `useState({...initialDate})`, this would only work if `initialDate` is an object, but again would be unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

you need to destructure the `props` like so:

```
const MyComponent = ({date, task}) => {
   const [myDate, setMyDate] = useState(date);
  console.log(myDate); //get the date here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like:

```
Import React, {useState} from "react";

const MyComponent = (props) => {
   const {date} = props //destructing
   console.log(props) // {date: "2019-11-26", task: "cooking"}
   const [date, setDate] = useState(date);
   console.log(date) 
   return (...)
}

export default MyComponent;
```

OR

```
Import React, {useState} from "react";

    const MyComponent = ({date}) => { //destructing
       const [date, setDate] = useState(date);
       console.log(date) 

       return (...)
    }

    export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: Just wanted to point that your first example would give an error because `date` would be declared twice

Answer (score 0):

You have to destructure the props for the destructuring to actually work.

try

```js
const MyComponent = ({date, task}) => {
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the date property is inside an object you should follow this approach:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const basket = {
  apples: 10,
  banana: 5
};

const SimpleComp = () => {
  const [{ apples, banana }, setBasket] = useState({ ...basket });

  return (
  <div>
    <button
      onClick={() =>
        setBasket((currentState) => ({
          ...currentState,
          apples: currentState.apples + 1,
          banana: currentState.banana + 1
        }))
      }
    >
    Add Fruit
    </button>
    <div> Apples : {apples} </div>
    <div> Banana : {banana} </div>
  </div>
 );
};

 export default SimpleComp;
```

where to useState is been provided a copy of basket thus respecting immutability, try yourself [code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-kapitsa-eqdov?file=/src/App.js)

or in case of simple date variable:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const actualDate = new Date()
const actualDateToday = actualDate.getDate()
console.log(actualDateToday);

const MyComponent = () => {
  console.log(actualDate) // {date: "2019-11-26", task: "cooking"}
  const [date, setDate] = useState(actualDateToday);
  console.log(date) // {date: "2019-11-26, task: "cooking"}
    
  return (   
    <div>
       <p> Date Today: {actualDateToday} </p>
      <button 
         onClick={() => setDate(date => date + 1)} >
         Add a day
      </button>
  
    <p> Date Tomorrow: {date}</p>

    </div>  
  );
 }
 export default MyComponent
```

try here [code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-kapitsa-eqdov?file=/src/App.js:0-672)