# Conditional set state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this component that changes background color based on the school's rating.

Between `1` to `10`, if the school's rating `3` and below should be `orange`, between `4` and `7` and should be `yellow`, `8` and above should be `green`. If the school does not have a rating (`null`), should be `gray`.

Here's my attempt:

```
...

  const [bg, setBg] = useState('gray')

  const Single = ({rating, name, distance}: Single) => {
    if (rating && rating <= 3) {
      setBg(`orange`)
    } else if (rating && rating >= 4 && rating <= 7) {
      setBg(`yellow`)
    } else if (rating && rating >= 8) {
      setBg(`green`)
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <span backgroundColor={bg}>
          {rating !== null ? rating : `NA`}
        </span>
      </div>
    )
  }

...
```

But now everything is `green`, even though I tested with various numbers.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) here

```
const bg = useMemo(() => {
    if (rating && rating <= 3) {
        return 'orange'
      } else if (rating && rating >= 4 && rating <= 7) {
        return 'yellow'
      } else if (rating && rating >= 8) {
        return 'green'
      }
}, [rating])
```

so now `useMemo` function callback will be called only if the value of `rating` gets changed and save the returnd value to `const bg`

if you are expecting the background-color of the span to be set based on the value of `bg`, you have to change the span definition as below

```
<span style={{backgroundColor: bg}}>...
```

Comment: Alternatively just do it without hooks, I don't think such a simple condition would make it worthwhile to cache the result of it. You can calculate the correct background color on each re-render.

Answer (score 2):

See the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) and the code samples within. `useState` must be called *within* the body of your component, like this:

```
const Single = ({rating, name, distance}: Single) => {
    const [bg, setBg] = useState('gray')

    if (rating && rating <= 3) {
      setBg(`orange`)
    } else if (rating && rating >= 4 && rating <= 7) {
      setBg(`yellow`)
    } else if (rating && rating >= 8) {
      setBg(`green`)
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <span backgroundColor={bg}>
          {rating !== null ? rating : `NA`}
        </span>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: @Rario because you are setting using `setBg` unconditionally (if you copied my code exactly), everytime a render is happening, regardless of if `rating` has actually changed, `setBg` is run again, causing yet another render and so on and so forth. Derived state based on props is generally done using `useEffect` or `useMemo` - see another SO question on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54625831/how-to-sync-props-to-state-using-react-hooks-setstate

Comment: Here in this code, each time the state gets updated component will get re-render. And on each render you are again setting the state and the loop goes on hence you are getting `Too many re-renders. .....`.