# useReducer in sub-components without additional render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, immer.js

I have a dashboard app that processes data streams and user actions via `useReducer` and `immer` to update the state.  These updates are available when React is ready to render.

I would like to invite others to make their own dashboard widgets for my app.  These widgets would be driven by the derived state from the dashboard's reducer.

Some complex widgets might want to also `useReducer` locally.  They might have their own local data streams and inputs.  Herein lies a design problem - *widgets that `useReducer` will be one render behind the rest of the dashboard!*

In my understanding, this is because output from the dashboard `useReducer` is only available just before a render, which means widgets driven by this data that want to `useReducer` locally must update via `useEffect` and thereby wait another render to draw their state.

Possible solutions:

- "lift state up" into the dashboard, but this breaks a clean
  separation of interests - the state of one widget is not relevant to
  the other widgets.  It will make maintenance a chore and cumbersome.
- `useMemo` in widgets to wrangle and process data before
  rendering.  To ensure state is not lost, I could also have `useMemo`
  update and return a value initially generated by `useRef`.  This seems... like an anti-pattern.

Comment: this looks promising => https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-getderivedstatefromprops found here => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54625831/how-to-sync-props-to-state-using-react-hooks-setstate