# How do you update the state of an array value in a useState such as this

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I have a useState in nextjs that has values like this:

```
const [sampleData, setSampleData] = useState({
     value1: ''
     value2: ''
     value3: []
   });
```

If I want to update the state of value1 for instance while keeping the rest of the state, I would do something like this:

```
setSampleData({...sampleData, value1: 'new value'});
```

This works. However, if I want to update the state of value3 which is an array and still keep the previous array contents it has before, how do I achieve this?
Doing something like this would replace the entire state of value3 array with the new set of arrays:

```
 setSampleData({...sampleData, value3: [new array]});
```

Is it possible or should I simply use another format entirely such as `useReducer` hook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an inner spread such as:

```js
setSampleData({
  ...sampleData,
  value3: [...sampleData.value3, 'new value']
});
```

Answer (score 0):

currecntly you have some options to achieve this,

Option1:

```
 setSampleData({...sampleData, value3: [...sampleData.value3, newValue]});
```

Option2:

```
const temp = {...sampleData}
temp.value3.push(newValue)
setSampleData({...temp});
```

Comment: Option2 can still cause rerendering issues since you're still modifying the original `value3` array from the original state. When you modify a nested value you need to also update all the levels of nesting leading down to that nested value like you have with your first example.

Comment: you are right, it needed to be copied not only referenced, good catch

Comment: No worries, even with the edit you made though, you could still face issues. For example, if you had a component and were passing `value3` into it like so `<SomeComponent someProp={sampleData.value3} />`, and the `SomeComponent` was memoized,  then `value3` in this case is still the same reference to what it was beforehand, so `SomeComponent` won't rerender even though you've changed it.

Comment: but isn't changing props force re-render the child component? 

small snippet: 
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/elastic-tdd-h1o06r?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A22%2C13

Comment: Yes, but not if the child componennt is memoized and you're passing the child an object, for example: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/elastic-tdd-h1o06r?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A22%2C13

Comment: But that's not the only case, for example, a common react pattern is to use useEffect() to listen to prop changes (such as exaplained here: [How to sync props to state using React hooks : setState()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54626764)), which while I don't really agree with this pattern, if used, it wouldn't work if the prop was `temp.value3` as the object reference is still the same. Other examples of how this could cause issues are also provided in the new React docs:  https://react.dev/learn/updating-arrays-in-state#updating-objects-inside-arrays and

Comment: here: https://react.dev/learn/updating-objects-in-state#objects-are-not-really-nested. It's subtle, and most probably the above code for option2 will work for most cases, but there are cases where it will cause issues, and to avoid those head-scratching scenarios, it's best to update all levels of nesting the encapsulated the item being updated.

Answer (score 0):

For adding extra logic to the setter, You can also pass a callback function to the state setter as such (*instead of just the new state*)

You can refer [the docs](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) to read more about it, but I guess this should work for your case.

```js
setSampleData((prevSampleData) => {
  const newSampleData = {...prevSampleData};
  newSampleData?.value3.push("New Sample") // add your own logic here
  return newSampleData
});
```

The returned value of this callback is what gets set as the new state

Comment: This modifies the original state with `.push()` so this will cause issues with rerendering, especially if `value3` is being used within the returned JSX (FYI @kingNodejs)

Comment: For object values, it is safer to return a new object instead of mutating the old one: `const newSampleData = {...prevSampleData};`

Comment: @PJaoko thanks for pointing this out, updated the answer with this

Comment: Your updated code can still cause issues on some scenarios. For example if the array at value3 is referenced in some other state, or if it’s passed to a memoized component. Coping just the top level object isn’t enough